# How to implement div(a/b) of floating point type through 1/b * a?

Tags: floating-point, cuda, division

I need to use the transcendental function `RCP`(rcp(b) == 1 / b) to implement floating-point type division. I need to calculate `c=rcp(b)` first, and then `result = c * a` to get the result(a/b).However, due to the accuracy error generated by the `rcp` function, the final result will also generate errors.What methods can I use to correct errors?I refer to the floating-point division implemented by `cuda`.You can see the implementation through the generated `sass` instruction，but I cannot understand the details.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to calculate `c` first? If you want accuracy, just divide `a / b` directly. CUDA hardware does division accurately since compute-capability 2.0

Comment: @njuffa Thank you for your answer. Reverse engineering is complex and I am currently learning this knowledge. Can you recommend any relevant literature to me？

Comment: @njuffa Thank you very much for your answer. Your answer can always help me, thank you.

Comment: In the case of repeated division by a (loop-)invariant value, according to my testing the compiler  (`nvcc`) will often discover it and do this optimization for you.

Comment: @njiuffa I have a question and hope to get an answer. When using the fast path calculation, can we get the correct result by using separate multiplication and addition instead of the FMA instruction? Can we implement floating-point division using the Newton iteration method if FMA instructions are not supported? Can we use Dekker's algorithm to achieve higher precision multiplication and addition instead of FMA?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an approximate reciprocal `c ~ 1/b`, you can refine it using one (or multiple) step(s) of Newton-Raphson refinements:

```
c = c*(2.0 - c*b)
```

(N.B., if your reciprocal is slightly biased, you can tweak the `2.0` constant a bit, to get better results).

Alternatively, or additionally, if you have an approximate reciprocal `c`, you can refine the division, by adding the remainder of the division times the reciprocal:

```
result = c*a;
remainder = a-b*result
result = result + c*remainder
```

The last two operations are ideally computed using a fused multiply-add (`fma`) instruction, if your hardware supports it.

---

Note: Using these techniques you will likely be able to reach +-1 ULP precision, but a perfectly precisely rounded result is much more difficult. Also be aware of handling border cases (divisions involving NaN, infinity, zero, or very large/small numbers).

Comment: thank your answer. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438932/how-to-refine-floating-point-division-on-fma-capable-gpus/65445072#65445072)has the answer I need,but I cannot understand the details. I will study the relevant literature recommended by njuffa.